# Xcode: minimum font size ignored on label under stack view

Tags: ios, uilabel, uistackview, xcode8.2

I'm trying to build a layout that can work on every size of iPhone (portrait only) and I'm using Stack views. Now, I was able to create a good layout using multiple stack views but I've found a problem with a UILabel: 
On my layout there are several elements in a vertical stack; they all have a fixed height except for a label that needs to resize based on the iPhone version, however, I cannot use the minimum font size on autoshrink, it's basically ignore it. There are no constraints on the Label.

For now, there is no code done yet, just working on the storyboard.

Any idea how I can make it works?

Comment: please review this post for best results when using this site http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Images of the problem, your expected outcome and any non-default constraint information for each object.